# Determining an element's opacity:hover value with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Let's say that you've set some class's opacity:hover with CSS:

```
.my_div_class:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

You can do the following to determine the element's default state opacity:

```
$(".my_div_class").css("opacity");
```

How do you determine the element's :hover opacity? Something along the lines of this idea:

```
$(".my_div_class:hover").css("opacity");
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it... because calling `css("opacity")` works with the computed styles... so unless the element is actually hovered the hover related styles will not be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle - Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68Jk7/)

HTML Part

```
<div class="my_div_class">
  <a href="#hello"> HELLO </a> 
</div>
```

JS Part

```
alert($(".my_div_class").css("opacity"));//default

$(".my_div_class").hover(function () {

  alert($(this).css("opacity"));//on hover

});
```

Comment: Thank you. So there's really no way to do it other than actually triggering the element's hover styling and then querying the opacity property?